# How to create multiple imageviews with same height and width

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I wanted to create atleast 50 imageViews with onClickListener on each of them.
What is the quickest way to create each of them with same height and width?

thanks in advance

Comment: Use a ViewGroup that uses an adapter to populate it with child views. Look into GridView.

Answer (score 0):

As said by chRyNaN, you can do this using a GridView, which will look like a picture gallery. Here is a quick example of the GridView in XML with some useful attributes you can look into if needed:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="100dp" />
```

You have to use an adapter to fill the content. It work very similarly to ListViews. The adapter inflates a layout and set it into a cell of the grid. Here is an example:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    // List of URIs of the images to be displayed
    private List<String> values;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> values ){
        super(context, -1, values);
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        String currentSource = values.get(position);

        imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse( currentSource ));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Then, you can have an Activity that looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_photo_gallery);

    // Get grid
    GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.bma_gallery_grid);

    List<String> src = new ArrayList<>();
    // Add Strings to src here

    // Create and set adapter
    GalleryAdapter adapter = new GalleryAdapter(this, src);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set OnItemClickListener
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

This is just an example. You can fill your ImageView with drawables, URLs, etc.